# SQL Server stored procedure with OPENJSON: How to determine insert or update?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

This is my 1st attempt at `openjson` & I'm trying to setup a stored procedure that passes in multiple records and either inserts or updates the record into the table. I can setup the basic insert or update query using my `openjson`, however my problem is I don't know how to determine if the current record needs to be inserted or updated based on json values.

Here's a quick, basic example. I pass in json data with 2 orders that I want to insert/update in the `dbo.Orders` table.

The 1st order I pass in has `OrderId = 123`, so since I know the record already exists, I need to update it. The 2nd order however, has an `OrderId = 0`. So this one doesn't exist in the database & needs to be inserted.

How would I do that?

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(2048) = N'[  
   {  
     "Order": {  
       "OrderId":123,  
       "Number":"SO43659",  
       "Date":"2011-05-31T00:00:00"  
     },  
     "AccountNumber":"AW29825",  
     "Item": {  
       "Price":2024.9940,  
       "Quantity":1  
     }  
   },  
   {  
     "Order": {  
       "Number":"SO43661",  
       "Date":"2011-06-01T00:00:00"  
     },  
     "AccountNumber":"AW73565",  
     "Item": {  
       "Price":2024.9940,  
       "Quantity":3  
     }  
  }  
  ]'  
 SELECT * FROM OpenJson(@json);

 --Here's where I need to do an insert/update.  Not sure how, but here's the gist:
 --If Json's Order.OrderId > 0
 --BEGIN
 -- UPDATE dbo.Orders WHERE OrderId = <Json's Order.OrderId>
 --END
 --ELSE
 --BEGIN
 --  INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (all values)
 --END
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What are the values you are specifically looking to `INSERT`/`UPDATE` here? Have you had a look at `MERGE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Larnu mentioned in his comment, **MERGE** is what you're looking for.

Here's an example that you can run in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(2048) = N'[  
   {"Order":{"OrderId":123,"Number":"SO43659","Date":"2011-05-31T00:00:00"},"AccountNumber":"AW29825","Item":{"Price":2024.9940,"Quantity":1}},  
   {"Order":{"Number":"SO43661","Date":"2011-06-01T00:00:00"},"AccountNumber":"AW73565","Item":{"Price":2024.9940,"Quantity":3}}
]';

/* ORDERS TABLE MOCK-UP */
DECLARE @Orders table (
    OrderId int, OrderNumber varchar(10), OrderDate datetime, AccountNumber varchar(10), ItemPrice decimal(18,4), ItemQuantity int
);

/* INSERT A RECORD THAT WILL BE UPDATED BY THE MERGE */
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES
    ( 123, 'SO43659', '2011-05-31 00:00:00.000', 'AW29825', 2024.9940, 5 ); -- Quantity will be updated to 1 via the MERGE.

/* SHOW ORDERS STARTING RESULTSET */
SELECT * FROM @Orders;

/* PERFORM ORDERS MERGE TO UPDATE/INSERT ROWS */
MERGE @Orders AS ord
USING (
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON( @json ) WITH (
        OrderId int '$.Order.OrderId',
        OrderNumber varchar(10) '$.Order.Number',
        OrderDate datetime '$.Order.Date',
        AccountNumber varchar(10) '$.AccountNumber',
        ItemPrice decimal(18,4) '$.Item.Price',
        ItemQuantity int '$.Item.Quantity'
    )
) AS jsn
ON
    ord.OrderId = jsn.OrderId
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        OrderNumber = jsn.OrderNumber,
        OrderDate = jsn.OrderDate,
        AccountNumber = jsn.AccountNumber,
        ItemPrice = jsn.ItemPrice,
        ItemQuantity = jsn.ItemQuantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ( OrderId, OrderNumber, OrderDate, AccountNumber, ItemPrice, ItemQuantity )
    VALUES ( jsn.OrderId, jsn.OrderNumber, jsn.OrderDate, jsn.AccountNumber, jsn.ItemPrice, jsn.ItemQuantity );

/* SHOW THE MERGED RESULTSET */
SELECT * FROM @Orders;
```

The initial resultset of `@Orders` is:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
| OrderId | OrderNumber |        OrderDate        | AccountNumber | ItemPrice | ItemQuantity |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
|     123 | SO43659     | 2011-05-31 00:00:00.000 | AW29825       | 2024.9940 |            5 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
```

After performing the MERGE, the updated `@Orders` resultset is:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
| OrderId | OrderNumber |        OrderDate        | AccountNumber | ItemPrice | ItemQuantity |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
| 123     | SO43659     | 2011-05-31 00:00:00.000 | AW29825       | 2024.9940 |            1 |
| NULL    | SO43661     | 2011-06-01 00:00:00.000 | AW73565       | 2024.9940 |            3 |
+---------+-------------+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+
```

You can see that the `MERGE` inserted the new record for **Number** *SO43661* and updated **OrderId** *123*'s *ItemQuantity* from *5* (its initial value) to *1*.